# Let $M $be a closed dense subspace of Hilbert space. Then prove that $M=H$

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces

$M$ closed $\Rightarrow$ If $u_n\in$ M and $u_n\to u$ then $u \in M$

$M$ dense in $H$ $\Rightarrow$ $\forall u \in H \ \exists u_n\in M: u_n\to u$

$M$ subspace of $H$ $\Rightarrow$ $M \subset$ H

How I prove that $M$ is in fact the Hilbert space $H$?

Answer (score 1):

On *any* topological space $X$, the only subset $S$ which is both closed and dense is $X$ itself. That's so because $S=\overline S=X$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $u\in H$. Then, since $M$ is dense, there exists $(u_n)\subset M$ such that $u_n\to u$. Since $M$ is closed, $u\in M$. So, $H\subset M\subset H$, i.e., $M = H$.